# Autocomplete onClick location map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i have a script that haves 2 input fields, the origin and destination, and based in this information outpus the zone i am. And is working fine, if anybody try to test it putting the address the autocomplete works a charm, the only problem im having is including a feature that is inserting the address autcomplete by mouse click, the autocomplete doesnt fireup, just frezes. All this logic is inserted in a eventlister above:

```
var origin_input = document.getElementById('origin-input');
  var destination_input = document.getElementById('destination-input');

var counter = 0;
  //Add listener
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {

  pos.lat = event.latLng.lat();
  pos.lng = event.latLng.lng();


  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.lat, pos.lng);
      geocoder.geocode({       
        latLng: latLng     
        }, 
        function(responses) 
        {     

           if (responses && responses.length > 0) 
           {        

            counter+=1; 
            if(counter == 1){
              origin_input.value= responses[0].formatted_address;
            }else if(counter == 2){
              destination_input.value=responses[0].formatted_address;
              //console.log(responses[0].formatted_address);    
            }

           } 
           else 
           {       
             alert('Not getting Any address for given latitude and longitude.');     
           }   
        }
);

})
```

Script Link:
http://jsbin.com/mujedamoqo/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by *"the autocomplete doesnt fireup, just frezes"*, you only set the value of the input's, and this works for me.

What didn't work: after 2 clicks counter will be larger than 2, and none of both conditions will match anymore.

Fix(will toggle between the 2 inputs) :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {

  pos.lat = event.latLng.lat();
  pos.lng = event.latLng.lng();


  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.lat, pos.lng);
      geocoder.geocode({       
        latLng: latLng     
        }, 
        function(responses) 
        {     

           if (responses && responses.length > 0) 
           {        
            counter=(counter)?0:1; 
            if(counter){
              origin_input.value= responses[0].formatted_address;
              origin_autocomplete.set('place',responses[0]);
              google.maps.event.trigger(origin_autocomplete,'place_changed');
            }else {
              destination_input.value=responses[0].formatted_address;
              destination_autocomplete.set('place',responses[0]);
              google.maps.event.trigger(destination_autocomplete,'place_changed');
            }

           } 
           else 
           {       
             alert('Not getting Any address for given latitude and longitude.');     
           }   
        });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for this detail, but still is not resolving the real issue, the functionality isnt working when using onclick, try inserting in the origin "Maia" and select any of the data appearing in the autocomplete, than insert in the destination "Porto" and insert any data from the autocomplete, than you will see the script interacting, something that doesnt happen when using onClick

Comment: As I said, it wasn't clear what the issue is(for me the autocomplete in the example doesn't work at all, impossible to type into the fields ). However, changing the value of the inputs doesn't modify the place and also doesn't trigger any event for the autocomplete, you'll need to do it on your own(I've modified the code above)